# How do I switch execution orders on the same button?

Tags: java, android

please help
I want to put several execution orders for the same button
I mean when i press the button for the first time does a certain thing
When pressed for the second time do another thing, and so on up to ten pressure
i tried this code but it did not work

```
public class ChickenBlanche extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
Button b1;
int i=0;


b1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btns);

    b1.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @SuppressLint("WrongConstant")
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if(i == 0)
            {
                Intent in = new Intent();
                in.putExtra( REG_INT_TAG, quantity1);
                setResult(RESULT_OK,in);
                finish();

            }
            else if(i==1)
            {
                Intent in = new Intent();
                in.putExtra( REG_INT_TAG1, quantity1);
                setResult(RESULT_OK,in);
                finish();
            }
        }
    } );
```

He did the first condition always and ignored the second condition
I read on the Stack OverFlow site this code

```
 public void functionName(View v)
{
    switch (v.getId())   // v is the button that was clicked
    {
       case (R.id.button1):  // this is the oddball 
       ...do stuff
       break;
    default:   // this will run the same code for any button clicked that doesn't have id of button1 defined in xml
        ...do other stuff
    break;
    }
}
```

but I did not really know how to apply it to my button

Comment: Are you incrementing i every time you click (or finish executing the first click task)? If not then i remains 0 and always the first if block will be executed. What are you trying to do on every button click?

Comment: @Rabee Send data but in each new click ignores the data sent in the first time and only recognizes the new data

Comment: Where are you sending the new data?

Comment: To the main activity but by different name

Answer (score 0):

Try the following example:

1) Demo4.class:------------

```
public class Demo4 extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button b;
public static final String WHICH = "which";
private SharedPreferences p;
public static final String REG_INT_TAG = "reg_int_tag";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_2);

    p = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("p_key",
            0);

    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (p != null) {
                switch (p.getInt(WHICH, 0)) {
                    case 0:
                        result("A");
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        result("B");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        result("C");
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        result("D");
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        result("E");
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        result("F");
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        result("G");
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        result("H");
                        break;
                    case 8:
                        result("I");
                        break;
                    case 9:
                        result("J");
                        break;
                    default:
                        result("A");
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

private void result(String value){

    Intent in = new Intent();
    in.putExtra(REG_INT_TAG,value);
    setResult(RESULT_OK,in);
    finish();
}

}
```

2) mainActivity.class:-------

```
public class mainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button b2;
    private SharedPreferences p;
    private final int ACTIVITY_2 = 12345;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        p = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("p_key",
                0);

        b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b2);
        b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(mainActivity.this , Demo4.class);
                startActivityForResult(i , ACTIVITY_2);
            }
        });
    }

    public void setInt(String Name, int value){
        if(p != null){
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = p.edit();
            editor.putInt(Name, value);
            editor.apply();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode == ACTIVITY_2){
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                if(data != null){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext() , data.getStringExtra(Demo4.REG_INT_TAG) , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    updateWhich();
                }
            }
        }
    }


private void updateWhich(){

    if(p != null){
        int which = p.getInt(Demo4.WHICH , 0);
        setInt(Demo4.WHICH, (which >= 0 && which < 9) ? which + 1 : 0);
        // if which is between 0 including and 9 excluding increment which otherwise which = 0.
    }
}

}
```

3) activity_2.xml:--------

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Click"
    android:id="@+id/b"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

4) activity_main.xml:--------

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="open 2"
    android:id="@+id/b2"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: I thank you and understood all your answer proposed but with regard to the fourth step, can you explain to me more where I can put it setInt (WHICH,1)

Comment: Maybe before finish(); or in the on Destroy() method of the activity or you can even do that in your mainActivity.

Answer (score 0):

Increment the i value at every time on Button press.
have a look code

```
b1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btns);

b1.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
    @SuppressLint("WrongConstant")
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        if(i == 0)
        {
            Intent in = new Intent();
            in.putExtra( REG_INT_TAG, quantity1);
            setResult(RESULT_OK,in);
            finish();

        }
        else if(i==1)
        {
            Intent in = new Intent();
            in.putExtra( REG_INT_TAG1, quantity1);
            setResult(RESULT_OK,in);
            finish();
        }

        i=i+1;//increment i value on button click at every time.

         if(i=>maxValue){//If i value reach maximum point then should reset also
              i=0;
             }      
    }
} );
```